# Changes to k8s configMap are rolled back after saving

Tags: kubernetes

I have Ansible AWX deployed in k8s cluster (https://github.com/ansible/awx-operator/).
I am trying to modify configMap to change nginx settings, but all changes are rolled back in ~30 seconds after saving.

[congimap.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77tTu.png)

I've tried to use kubectl edit, patch and replace and the result is always same.

Why my changes are rolled back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like another controller is also watching the configmap. If the other controller uses server-side-apply, you can check via the following, which controller updates the configmap too:

```
kubectl get cm <name> --show-managed-fields -o yaml
```

and then check the managed-fields section.

Comment: Thank you, but there are no managed fields in my configmap:

$ kubectl get cm awx-awx-configmap --show-managed-fields
NAME                DATA   AGE
awx-awx-configmap   5      4d22h

Comment: ah sry, add the `-o yaml` to get more verbose output